# How to send email "from" customer's email using SES

Tags: amazon-ses

I am a beginner developing my first site and I'm using AWS as my hosting platform. On my site I have a Contact Us form where the user can input their name, email and message then hit submit.

I am using SES to send the email from the Contact Us form, but I have a problem. I am aware that SES can only send emails from a verified email address, however I would like to set my From header to be the email address entered by the customer. This is so that when the mail arrives in my mail client it shows the customer's name on the left, next to the subject, before I click into the email.

I tried setting the Sender header to my verified email so that I could use the From header as the customer's one, but it made no difference.

I have been following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html) but as soon as I change `<sender@example.com>` to anything other than my verified email address it won't work.

The bash script which I'm using to send the email looks like this:

```
emailInput='AUTH LOGIN
*myBase64EncodedSMTPLogin*
*myBase64EncodedSMTPPassword*
MAIL FROM: '"${1}"'
RCPT TO: *my ses verified email address*
DATA
From: '"${2}"' <'"${1}"'>
To: 
Subject: Message from *mysite.com*
'"${3}"'
.
QUIT'

echo "$emailInput" > ./tmpEmailInput.txt 

openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect *aws smtp endpoint* < tmpEmailInput.txt

rm ./tmpEmailInput.txt
```

In the above code, the arguments are as follows:

- The first argument is the customer's email address.
- The second is their name.
- The third is their message.

If I change $1 in both places to my verified email address it works, but then in my mail client is says "me" as the sender, because the verified email address is both sending and receiving. I can only see the customer's name in the field at the top once I click into the email.

I would greatly appreciate some advice.

Thank you.